# return response.data value of $http in a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to call $http service within functions so I don't get nested callbacks. Without function scope it look like this:

```
      $http.post('/verify_stripe_token', {email:$routeParams.email,token:$routeParams.t})
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response.data) // return 1
      });
```

I want to use if(valid_token() == 1){} so I tried

```
function valid_token(){
      $http.post('/verify_stripe_token', {email:$routeParams.email,token:$routeParams.t})
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
    }
```

Nothing worked? I do console.log(valid_token()) I got undefined.

Comment: @schroffl I know in jquery I just simply do return $.ajax but hey this is angular

Comment: But it's the same problem, you can't return `response.data` since `$http.post` is an asynchronous call.

Comment: @gothdo, not entirely a duplicate since OP isn't returning anything at all from the function currently

Comment: @charlietfl But they do attempt to return from the function. I think they thought that the return statement in the inner function would work for the outer function too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `valid_token()` function doesn't return anything.

Next, you can't do `if(valid_token() == 1)` since `$http` requests are asynchronous

You would need to do something like:

```
function valid_token(){
  // return the promise
  return $http.post('/verify_stripe_token', {email:$routeParams.email,token:$routeParams.t})
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });
}

valid_token().then(function(data){
  if(data == 1){
     // do what you need here
  }
})
```

Comment: this look ugly haha. I have 2 condition, the second one is to check whether valid_token is true or false.

Comment: well check both conditions. Need to be more specific if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

Response is actually a JSON.Print response.data to confirm it and handle it the JSON way

Comment: Further,user of $q promise would be appropriate in this case.